# How can I auto-populate an established address from a database using Google Maps or another similar service?

Tags: forms, maps, street-address, form-fields

I'm creating a form that allows users to enter the address of a location among other things. I current have the form set up as one single field for the number and street, and then individual fields for the city, state, and zip. I am allowing users to submit locations outside of the United States as well. I realize that other countries have addresses set up differently than the U.S. Is there a way to work with google or some other maps service to auto populate an established address in a database. For instance, when you create an event on Facebook, typing in the location of the event makes established locations and addresses from anywhere in the world appear to select from. How is this done?

I done a lot of googling on how this is done but all I can come up with is how to address a Google Map for a specific address onto a website, which I already know how to do and isn't what I'm going for. I see some places saying that Facebook utilizes Mapbox, but other places that says they use OpenStreetMap. I've searched addresses on OpenStreetMap's actual site before. I don't see anywhere really addressing what I'm looking for.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.